# Sending an email via Google Groups

Tags: java, email, smtp, google-apps, google-groups

We has successfully managed to send emails from a java web application via the Google Apps SMTP server.  That of course means that we need to add a paying user to the Google Apps as you need a username and password to have access to the SMTP server.

Is there any way we can make this work with a Google Groups and avoid adding an extra user?

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: don't think there is an option to use groups